# How to disable soft wraps for single file in TextMate 2?

Tags: text-editors, textmate-2

I want to keep "Soft Wrap" enabled by default, however for some files I need to disable it so I will not need to click "Disable Soft Wrap" every time I open the file.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely can. Using https://gist.github.com/dvessel/1478685 as a reference, I'd say you want something like this in your ~/.tm_properties file:

```
[ *.txt ]
softWrap         = true

[ text ]
softWrap         = false
```

Comment: However you should put `[ *.txt ]` on the top and do you overrides below. The lower setting is the bigger priority it gets.

Comment: That's really odd, not something I knew. Answer updated to reflect.